# JS recursive function meets condition for return; does not terminate

Tags: javascript, recursion

To practice recursive functions in JS, I'm trying to write one that finds GCD (greatest common divisor) of 2 integers via Euclidean method.

Code:

```
function euclidean(a,b){
if(!Number.isInteger(a)||!Number.isInteger(b)){alert("Both arguments must be integers!")}
else if(a<b){let temp=a; let a=b; let b=temp};
let rem=a%b;
console.log(rem); 
if(rem==0){console.log("The GCD is "+b); return b}else{euclidean(b,rem);};
}
console.log(euclidean(270,192));
```

Console output is 78, 36, 6, 0, undefined ( [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN6eg.png) )

I got *undefined*, then added the console.log's. The numbers logged seem to indicate that each recursion loop is working as intended. Variable rem seems to reach 0, termination condition seems to be met and it's code begins executing (console prints "The GCD is " + b). However, the *return* statement doesn't return b and terminate the recursion. Why is that?

Comment: Are you always returning something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a return value from a recursive function, you need to return the recursive call.

```
function euclidean(a,b){
    if(!Number.isInteger(a)||!Number.isInteger(b)){
        alert("Both arguments must be integers!")
    }else if(a<b){
        let temp=a; let a=b; let b=temp
    };
    let rem=a%b;
    console.log(rem); 
    if(rem==0){
        console.log("The GCD is "+b); 
        return b;
    }else{
        return euclidean(b,rem);
    };
}
console.log(euclidean(270,192));
```

Like so.

An additional note; beware the scope of variables declared with **let**.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

```
let temp=a; let a=b; let b=temp
```

These variables won't exist outside of their **else** block scope.